# Is it possible to remove this redundancy from my XML schema?

Tags: xml, xsd, redundancy

I have the following problem:

I have two complexTypes, `foo` and `bar` with both the member `foobar`:

```
<xs:complexType name="foo">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="foobar" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="bar">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="foobar" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

To reduce redundancy, I want to declare a foobar as a complexType, which gets referenced in both `foo` and `bar`, something like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="foobar">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element type="xs:string />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

But this doesn't seem to be the right way. Is this actually possible in XML Schema?

Answer (score 4):

You are probably better off using an `xs:group` element for that rather than a complex type:

```
<xs:complexType name="foo">
    <xs:group ref="foobarGroup"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="bar">
    <xs:group ref="foobarGroup"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:group name='foobarGroup'>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="foobar" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>        
</xs:group>
```

You can't express the sequence directly as part of an `xs:complexType`.

Answer (score 1):

I have yet to check the following for correctness, but I believe you can do it like this:

```
  <xs:complexType name="hasFoobar" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="foobar" … />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

And then "extend" this abstract type:

```
  <xs:complexType name="foo">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="hasFoobar">
        …
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="bar">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="hasFoobar">
        …
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```